# Sending parameters to find which option of intent chooser is clicked while showing both camera and gallery option

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi I found the following code snippet from another question of stackoverflow to open Camera and Gallery Intent chooser combined. Here's the code.

```
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,null);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            cameraIntent.putExtra("Code", OPEN_CAMERA); <-- Not working


            Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, galleryIntent);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Snap Option");
            chooser.putExtra("Code", OPEN_GALLERY);    <-- Not working

            Intent[] intentArray =  {cameraIntent}; 
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooser,1);
```

What I want to do is check which intent chooser was clicked when I will be in the `onActivityResult` . But as mentioned in the code I tried to `putExtra` params to differentiate and in the `onActivityResult` I am doing the following to get the code.

```
int Code = intent.getExtras().getInt("Code");
```

But this gives me a `NullPointerException` . How can I do this please help ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to used something for pick the image from..

Like **alert box,dialog,custom dialog** and many more.i am just guide you how to used alertdialog.

```
final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library","Cancel" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    //you can take photo from camera
                    /*Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);*/
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                //you can pick photo from library/gallery
                 /*   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);*/
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
```